# @react-three/postprocessing no matching export from three.module.js for import "WebGLMultisampleRenderTarget"

Tags: reactjs, three.js, vite, react-three-fiber, post-processing

I installed react-three-fiber and I am trying to apply postprocessin, but I get this error

**No matching export in "node_modules/three/build/three.module.js" for import "WebGLMultisampleRenderTarget"**

here is an example:

```
  <EffectComposer disableNormalPass>
    <Bloom luminanceThreshold={1} mipmapBlur />
  </EffectComposer>
  <Environment background preset="sunset" blur={0.8} />
```

I did investigation but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, managed to fix this by downgrading `@react-three/drei` to `9.32.4` and `three` to `0.145.0`

I'm also using the following:

```
"@react-three/drei": "^9.32.4",
"@react-three/fiber": "^8.8.7",
"@react-three/postprocessing": "^2.7.0",
"@types/three": "^0.149.0",
"postprocessing": "6.29.3",
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. It works with theatrejs and r3f.